# How to access an index in a vector in a map from strings to vectors

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

If I have the following code, which stores 3 vectors as values in an unordered_map and maps to them via the string in their first index as a key:

```
unordered_map<string, vector <vector<string>>> my_map;
vector<string> vec1 = {"banana", "apple"};
vector<string> vec2 = {"banana", "banana"};
vector<string> vec3 = {"banana", "pear"};

my_map["banana"].push_back(vec1);
my_map["banana"].push_back(vec2);
my_map["banana"].push_back(vec3);

cout << my_map["banana"][0] << my_map["banana"][1] << my_map["banana"][2];
```

How can I access specific indices of the unordered_map's vector? I tried to do this in the last line but it does not work. I have also tried using .at(0), etc instead of the double brackets but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_map["banana"][0]` is a `std::vector<std::string>`, so you can't output that directly. You could overload the `<<` operator, or just specify another index.

---

You have an `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>>`, where each key has a vector of vectors.

So `my_map["banana"].push_back(vec1)` pushes `vec1` to the main vector. If you want to access the values from `vec1`, you have to specify 2 indices, because:

```
my_map["banana"][0]                     [0]
        ^^^^^^   ^                       ^
         key     vector 0               element 0 in the vector
                 (in main vector)       at position 0 in the main vector
```

*Note: This will return `"banana"`*

---

If you want get `"pear"`, you would use:

```
my_map["banana"]    [2]                  [1]
       ^^^^^^^       ^                    ^  
         key         third vector         second element
                      (vec3)                ("pear")
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Stupid mistake by me. Thank you for the help!